# update div/photo slider in angular on a real tme

Tags: angularjs, real-time

Hi  thx for the support

I would like to build a slider of photos in angular 1 
the problem is that i have to listen to event add add the image of the vent and his details to the  view and show slider with the images . 
the last slide comes from left to right and push the other.

the big question is how I Listen to events from the server (the data is ready for me) and update on real time while there is  a change in the list

I need a directive ?rootscope ?
the directive/slider should be on 5-6  views of the application.

thx

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the research you put into trying to solve this so we can help pinpoint what you most need.

Comment: i dont know how to start @LeftyGBalogh  my question is how to start with real time data., I need to get from php server each 1 second the data and check it and update the list.

do I need broadcast from timeout service? , do I need to inject the service in the directive